# Alert the table header name when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, dom

How can the code be modified below, so as to return the name of the column header when the column header box is clicked by the user. Ie. if I click on the "File Number" box, a javascript alert box will alert me as to what the name of the column header (th) is "File Number" ect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#mstrTable {
     border: 1px solid black
}
#mstrTable td, th {
     border: 1px solid black
}

#mstrTable tr.normal td {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
#mstrTable tr.highlighted td {
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mstrTable">
     <thead>
      <tr> 
        <th>File Number</th>
        <th>Date1</th>
        <th>Date2</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Num.</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr> 
        <td>KABC</td>
        <td>09/12/2002</td>
        <td>09/12/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>0</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KCBS</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>Approved</td>
        <td>1&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>WFLA</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTSP</td>
        <td>09/15/2002</td>
        <td>09/15/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
(
  function( )
  {
      var trows = document.getElementById("mstrTable").rows;

      for ( var t = 1; t < trows.length; ++t )
      {
          trow = trows[t];
          trow.className = "normal";
          trow.onclick = highlightRow;
      }

      function highlightRow(e)
      {
      alert('Row is ' + (this.rowIndex-1))
          for ( var t = 1; t < trows.length; ++t )
          {
              trow = trows[t];
              trow.className = ( trow == this && trow.className != "highlighted") ? "highlighted" : "normal";
          }
      }
  }
)();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked into jQuery. This makes these sort of jobs simple.

Comment: I'd prefer not to load any libraries and extra files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is with all the looping! There is no need for the loops, use your event object which tells you what was clicked on!

```
//assumes one thead and one tbody

var table = document.getElementById("mstrTable");
var thead = table.getElementsByTagName("thead")[0];
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

tbody.onclick = function (e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var td = e.target || e.srcElement; //assumes there are no other elements inside the td
   var row = td.parentNode;
   row.className = row.className==="highlighted" ? "" : "highlighted";
}

thead.onclick = function (e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var th = e.target || e.srcElement;  //assumes there are no other elements in the th
   alert(th.innerHTML);
}
```

The above could be one click event for the whole table, I did not want to check for the element type that was clicked on.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wv74z/)

Comment: Your example works flawlessly, only one prob though, I still need to find out as to what the row number is. (I plan to do some db work later on and will require the row number)

Comment: And you get that with [`row.rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/tableRow.rowIndex). [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wv74z/)

Comment: Another problem too is that when another row is clicked, the existing row does not reset to white, so there looks like there are multiple rows selected.

Comment: row.rowIndex worked like a charm! Almost there though, only one more problem, is the multiple row selection.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qMgdY/)**.

```
  (
  function () {
      var trows = document.getElementById("mstrTable").rows;
      for (var t = 1; t < trows.length; ++t) {
          trow = trows[t];
          trow.className = "normal";
          trow.onclick = highlightRow;
      }
      var theads = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
      for (var t = 0; t < theads.length; t++) {
          thead = theads[t];
          thead.onclick = highlightHead;
      }
      function highlightRow(e) {
          alert('Row is ' + (this.rowIndex - 1))
          for (var t = 1; t < trows.length; ++t) {
              trow = trows[t];
              trow.className = (trow == this && trow.className != "highlighted") ? "highlighted" : "normal";
          }
      }
      function highlightHead(e) {
          alert('Head is ' + this.innerHTML.toString());
      }
  })();
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for alleviating my frustration. The DOM is still really new to me. I apparently have a lot to learn. Thank you so much for this code.